# Animate text using css

Tags: css

I am trying to animate the text using keyframes in css :

my html code:

```css
@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    content: "Animate"
  }
  50% {
    content: "text using"
  }
  100% {
    content: "CSS!!"
  }
}

.change-text::after {
  animation: animate 5s infinite;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p class="change-text">
    Text will change here
  </p>
</center>
```

But the text is not changing, help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: And what does that mean? What animation are you trying to apply? What's the starting point, what's the end point, what happens in the middle? Where did you get stuck? "*I am trying*" is not a problem description, so what problem are you facing?

Comment: Note that the `<center>` element has been obsolete for a decade or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is happening because you have not given `content` property in `after`. just add `content: "";` into to `.change-text::after`

```css
@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    content : "Animate"
  }
  50%{
    content : "text using"
  }
  100%{
    content : "CSS!!"
  }
}
.change-text::after{
  animation : animate 5s infinite;
  content: ""; // Added 
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="change-text">
    Text will change here
  </div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**Html Code:**

```
<center>
  <p class="change-text">
    Text will change here
    <span class="animated-text"></span>
  </p>
</center>
```

**CSS Code**

```
@keyframes animate{
    0%{
        content : "Enjoy";
    }
    20%{
        content : "animate";
    }
    50%{
        content : "text";
    }
    75%{
        content : "using";
    }
    100%{
        content : "CSS!!";
    }
}
.animated-text::after{
    content: ''; // Need to Add content
    color: red;
    animation : animate 5s infinite;
}
```